# How to use common CSS styles used in one component in Radium to other component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, radium

I have a two components and they use same layout/styling with different content. I use Radium in React.js.
I have used in-line styling in one of the component and want to use same styling to other component. 
I'm new to both Radium and React. Help me out!

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!!

Comment: Couldn't you just pass the variable containing your styles to the other component as a prop?

Comment: Are you using webpack ?

Comment: Give us some of your code.

Comment: yes I'm using webpack

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a shared external styles file and then import it in every component that needs it.

```
// styles.js
export default {
  base: {
    background: 'red'
  }
}

// components
import sharedStyles from 'path/to/styles.js';

@Radium
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        style={[
          sharedStyles.base
        ]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```